# Angularjs issue in getting id of clicked element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to get id of the clicked element in angularjs and it is working quite fine. Below is my code

**html**

```
<a href="#faqinner/contactform" class="clearfix" ng-click="getCateId($event)" id="{{option.id}}">
      <span class="icon">
          <img ng-if="option.icon!=null" ng-src="http://images.crownit.in/others/{{option.icon}}">
          <img ng-if="option.icon==null" ng-src="https://crownit.in/wp-content/themes/crownit-theme/images/faq_default_icon.png">
      </span>
      <span class="faq_name">{{option.name}}</span>
      <span class="arrow">
          <img src="images/right_arrow.png">
      </span>
    </a>
```

**controller**

```
$scope.getCateId = function(obj, $event){
    $rootScope.cateId = obj.target.id;
    console.log($rootScope.cateId);
};
```

The above code should return the id of the clicked `<a>` tag but the **problem** i am facing is there is more `<span>` in `<a>` tag so when i click on the space of span it target's the `<span>` tag which has no id but when i specifically click on the top free space where no inner `<span>` covered then it works fine.

How can i get the id of `<a>` even if i click on `<span>` space??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass the `option.id` to `ngClick` handler

```
<a  ng-click="getCateId(option.id)" id="{{option.id}}">
```

controller method

```
$scope.getCateId = function(optionId){
    console.log(optionId);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass id to `getCateId` function

```
<a  ng-click="getCateId(option.id)" id="{{option.id}}">

$scope.getCateId = function(id){
    //Do something
};
```